# Are these both prepositions?

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

During the height of the blizzard...

Would during and of both be prepositions, if so what would be the prepositional phrase for the two prepositions?

Comment: (During the height (of the blizzard))

Comment: Whether a word is a preposition can be readily found in a dictionary. [*During*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/during) | [*of*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/of)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, "during" and "of" are both prepositions.

The object of "during" is "the height of the blizzard."

The object of "of" is "the blizzard."

We have nested prepositional phrases.

It might be clearer how this nesting works in "during the blizzard's height." The meaning of "blizzard's height" and "height of the blizzard" is the same, but there is no "of" to complicate the analytic decomposition of the main phrase.